# all possible inner products in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Suppose $\langle., .\rangle: \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is an inner product.

What would be  all possible function forms of the inner products, i.e. would all of them have the forms

either $\langle x, y\rangle=ax_1y_1+bx_2y_2$ or   $\langle x, y\rangle=ax_1 y_2+b x_2y_1,   a,b\in \mathbb R$

or other forms are also possible?

How about $\mathbb R^n$$?$

Comment: An inner product requires that the only element such that $\langle u,u\rangle=0$ is the zero vector itself.  Note that for your second proposed form, the vector $u=(1,0)$ would give an output of zero.  You could weaken the condition in the question to be about semi-inner products instead (where the condition that the only element whose induced norm is zero is the zero vector itself is dropped).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By definition an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on a real vector space $V$ is a bilinear, symmetric and positive definite form. In the case of $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ all inner products have form $\langle x,y\rangle=x^TAy$, where $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Typesetting note, using `<` and `>` cause extra space to be inserted.  For inner product, use instead `\langle` and `\rangle` respectively.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Gram matrix defining the inner product (it has as entry at place $(i,j)$ the inner product of $e_i$ by $e_j$) is symmetric and positive definite (and conversely), you can characterize it with [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion): all principal minors should be positive.

In the case of a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix, say
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
this becomes
$$
a>0,\qquad ac-b^2>0
$$
For a $3\times 3$ matrix, say
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
b & d & e \\
c & e & f
\end{bmatrix}
$$
this is
$$
a>0,\quad
ad-b^2>0,\quad
adf+2bce-c^2d-ae^2-b^2f>0
$$